# Edit Arabic text/ content at Android Studio editor is almost impossible

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, editor

It is almost impossible to edit Arabic text in Android Studio!

For example I have the following string-aray:

```
<string-array name="countries">
        <item> - من خارج فلسطين - </item>
        <item> أذربيجان </item>
        <item> أرمينيا </item>
        <item> أستراليا </item>
        <item> أفغانستان </item>
        <item> ألبانيا </item>
        <item> ألمانيا </item>
        <item> أنتيغوا </item>
...
```

What I do is that I copy it to notepad, edit it, then paste back again!

It comes a real pain when the list is bigger and it is a major drawback for Android Studio!

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution might be to open the string.xml and all other resource files with an external editor since Arabic suport is crappy in android studio.

ٍSo i suggest to select string.xml right click and click show in explorer
then open it with your preferred text editor and change whatever you want.

Comment: this does the trick but its messy... wishing for another plugin maybe

Comment: This does not work for me. I've tried opening these files in gedit and emacs, and in each case they treat it exactly the same (and as poorly!) as in Android Studio.

Comment: Then please select another text editor that supports the desired feature like notepad++ or visual studio code